# Regex: How to match the "smallest" text matching my regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract some information from a text.

The text I currently retrieve is some kind of horoscope, with by example:

```
Aries Some random text
which is on multiple
lines and could content one
of the word above, as love for
example.
Love ★★★✩
Job ★★★✩
Energy ★★★✩
Libra Some random text
which is on multiple
lines and could content one
of the word above, as job for
example.
Love ★★★✩
Job ★★★✩
Energy ★★★✩
Taurus Some random text
which is on multiple
lines and could content one
of the word above, as energy for
example.
Love ★★★✩
Job ★★★★
Energy ★★★★
```

I've currently this regex to retrieve the differents values for one given sign:

```
Aries([\S\s]*)Love\s*([★✩]{1,4})\sJob\s*([★✩]{1,4})\sEnergy\s*([★✩]{1,4})
```

but the `[\S\s]*`is basically catching everything it can, and basically this match the whole text I gave in example.

So two possibility:

- How to match the "smallest" expression possible?
- How to get the all the text on multiple lines without ALSO getting the Love/Job/Energy header+stars?

Thank you!!!

Comment: You can use *ungreedy* patterns with `*?` instead of `*`.

Comment: Change the pattern as above (`[\s\S]*` -> `.*?` and compile the regex with `RegexOptions.Singleline` option) and grab what you get in `match.Groups[1].Vlaue`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In fact I found a much better solution, but since you closed it I cannot add it as answer. 
Well done sir

Comment: Yes, it can be done in a better way.

Comment: Then why close it and prevent users from giving a best answer in my case?